# How to stop Android 12 or 13 asking for password every time after lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, android-12, password-protection

I just upgraded from Android 11 to Android 12 and now It asks me every single time I unlock the screen. Before, it would ask me for the password only once every half an hour as I had configured it.

How can I get back to that behaviour in Android 12 that only ask me for the password once on a while?

UPDATE: Same situation in Android 13.

Comment: On Pixel 3a, it is on Settings - Security - Screen lock (the cog wheel) - Lock after screen timeout. The "Power button instantly locks" switch may also be relevant.

Comment: In Android 11 I could see that option, but I can't find it anymore in Android 12.

Comment: Could you mention the device model?

Comment: Yes: One Plus Nord Community Edition